# How to find the SPACE and replace with required text within COMMENT text only

Tags: xslt

Please suggest for, how to find and replace the ' ' (space) to 'SPACETEXT' within Comment text . (XSLT version 2).

Input XML:

```
<root>
  <para>First Text is <ceitalic>O</ceitalic><!--Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4--><!--Text6 Text7 Text8--><cesup>2</cesup></para>
  <para>Second text is <ceitalic>H</ceitalic> <!--Text9--><!--Text10--><cesup>2</cesup></para>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="comment()/text()">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="' '">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                 <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="regex-group(1)">SPACETEXT</xsl:when>
                 </xsl:choose>
             </xsl:matching-substring>
             <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
             </xsl:non-matching-substring>
           </xsl:analyze-string>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required OUTPUT:

```
 <root>
   <para>First Text is <ceitalic>O</ceitalic><!--Text1SPACETEXTText2SPACETEXTText3SPACETEXTText4--><!--Text6SPACETEXTText7SPACETEXTText8--><cesup>2</cesup></para>
   <para>Second text is <ceitalic>H</ceitalic> <!--Text9--><!--Text10--><cesup>2</cesup></para>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment nodes cannot contain text nodes. So, first of all, the match expression should look like:

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
```

Also, the code can be simplified by replacing `xsl:analyze-string` with XPath `replace()` function as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
    <xsl:comment>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., ' ', 'SPACETEXT')"/>
    </xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice suggestion about the 'comments'. It is working perfectly.